# size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow' error on jetson orin nano OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson-nano

I want to display the stream from the camera to the screen using opencv

Me device: Jetson-orin-nano, Arducam IMX477

When I run this code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 960)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 540)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imwrite('frame.jpg', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I got black screen all of the time

When I run this one:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink", cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 960)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 540)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imwrite('frame.jpg', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I got the error:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: That error simply says you have a blank frame (no size)!  Check your path and check the frame shape after trying to read it.

Comment: I dont think you may use cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH in a gstreamer input. And anyways you should not call that in the lioop.

Comment: I resolved this problem, thx